# Server specifies `charset=utf-8`, downloads as ISO-8859

Tags: apache, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a process on my server that generates GPX (a type of XML) files. The file uses UTF-8 encoding because of some accented characters, and specifies it in the head with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Also, on the Apache server I added `AddType` and `AddEncoding` directives so if you do a `HEAD` command or examine the headers in Chrome developer tools, you see

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8
```

However, if you use the `file` command on it after you've downloaded it, it reports:

```
# file 9f90063f.gpx
9f90063f.gpx: XML 1.0 document text, ISO-8859 text
```

This is causing problems for the people consuming the file since they're reporting that the program they're feeding the file is getting confused. How can I make it so the files download as utf-8 rather than ISO-8859?

Comment: 1) `application/octet-stream` implies binary, so encoding doesn't make sense. If it's XML you should declare some sort of XML 2) Is `file` right or not? Declared encoding has of course nothing to do with actual encoding.

Comment: I don't know how exactly `file` works but if your file doesn't contain any accented characters (i.e. characters outside the first 128 ASCII positions) it will be indistinguishable from a single-byte encoded file. Remember, UTF-8 is flexible in that only characters beyond the first 128 are  two bytes long and cause problems if not interpreted as UTF-8. Maybe that's the "problem" (which technically wouldn't be one). Can you confirm that files with accented characters lead to the same `file` output?

Comment: 1) If I specify `application/xml`, Chrome tries to display it rather than download it. Am I missing something to make it download?

Comment: 2) There is a third party program called EasyGPX that is evidently having problems with these files because it thinks they're ISO-8559 rather than UTF-8. I don't have access to that program, so I don't know what the problem is exactly.

Comment: You can add a `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="9f90063f.gpx"` header. But if you want to download it, why do you need `Content-Type` to be accurate?

Comment: Encoding is not magic. Just grab an hex editor and see what's there (or play with your text editor's "encoding" menu until accents display correctly). The browser will not alter the file.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I don't know if `Content-Type` is the actual problem. The file has accented characters, but they appear to all be in the ISO-8559 range - i.e. Ostersund uses 0xd6 for the first letter not 0xc396.

Comment: @PaulTomblin `Ö` in **Östersund** is [`U+00D6` aka LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d6/index.htm) and its UTF-8 encoding is (as you already point out) `c396`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments on the question, I was able to figure out that the problem wasn't in the download link, it was when I generated the file. I added a `binmode(XML, ":utf8")` and it appears to be encoded correctly.